# Python How do I toggle a GPIO from my E-mail inbox

Tags: python, gmail, raspberry-pi, gpio

so I have set out on a progect to program something to where whenever I get an E-mail it toggles a GPIO to turn on a LED can someone please help me figure out how to toggle the GPIO on my Raspberry Pi.
here is what i have so far

```
import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

mail.login('mygmail@gmail.com','mypassword')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to work with GPIO, there is a project `raspberry-gpio-python`, a python library that provides access to raspberry-pi GPIO, Find examples here: https://code.google.com/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage

According to check your email inbox, you can find duplicate questions on StackOverflow, for example have a look at this simple question: [Check unread count of Gmail messages with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953561/check-unread-count-of-gmail-messages-with-python)